# Can you add multiple jars in a jar file and then launch that jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am working  on a GUI application and would rather distribute just one jar as opposed to multiple ones.

Can you control this with the manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge your jars to one jar. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/java-easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file).

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use a custom class loader such as this one:

http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful when doing this. If the jars you are merging have manifest files with critical information - these can get lost, only the last file will get merged.

E.g. If you merge JavaMail - the manifest file is important. If you lose it - bad things csn happen.

The safest thing to do is to look at each jar file and check the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/java_warehouse/single_jar/). Use Netbeans 6.7.1 to combine multiple jars into 1 jar

Answer (score 0):

Create a Shaded jar which combines multiple jars into a single jar. Maven supports this functionality out of the box.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/