# running jar file inside other jar from java program

Tags: java, jar

I'm having problems running a jar file inside another jar file from a Java program. For example,
I have A.jar, which is in the packet a / b / c at B.jar, how can I run A.jar from the Java program.

How can i get A.jar from any place where B.jar exist?

A simple example would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Java doesn't (currently) support embedded Jars (Jar within Jar).  You can take a look at [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) which is a solution designed to try and provide this functionality, but I had issues with using additional dynamic class loaders with it, but it might fit your needs

Comment: If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, check in the project properties, there should be a way to add external JARs.

Comment: i mean, i would run A.Jar when my application running, how to refers A.jar when B.jar running

Comment: Try having a look at [Working with Manifest files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) and [Adding classes to the JAR file's classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I call class files that are within a jar library located in another jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258668/can-i-call-class-files-that-are-within-a-jar-library-located-in-another-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

To run a jar that requires another, you need to add that other jar to the classpath. [Have a look at this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29)