# Jar file cannot find the com.mysql.jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to make a application in java which connects to a mysql database. For this purpose I downloaded the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar` connector.

I also added the path of the above jar file in the CLASSPATH environment variable.

I created the application and executed the java files and it executed properly.

Then I created a jar file of the application and tried to execute it then i got the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at CanteenCounter.refresh(CanteenCounter.java:73)
    at CanteenCounter$1.actionPerformed(CanteenCounter.java:30)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I think the jar file is not able to find the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JAR file is an executable JAR file which you execute by using the `-jar` option, or by double-clicking it, then the `CLASSPATH` environment variable as well as the `-cp` or `-classpath` option will be ignored.

For executable JAR files, you must specify the classpath in the manifest file of the JAR.

See this page from Oracle's Java Tutorials for more details on specifying the classpath in the manifest file: [Working with Manifest Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

Answer (score 2):

Generally you do not want to use the CLASSPATH variable but rather the -cp flag to specify library location.

```
java  -cp /path/to/jar:/path/to/other/jar Main
```

Comment: but what if I want to create a executable jar file. I wanna open it witha  double click

Comment: Different question really, but a good answer to it can be found. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018257/how-to-combine-library-with-my-jar also here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jar/index.html

Comment: Thank you Mimisbrunnr  the IBM link was very helpful