# Packages and Exporting Jar files with Referenced Libraries Error

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, import

I have a program with multiple packages in my current Java Project.

I have also referenced some jars such as the Java Commons Library.

I am planning on releasing my program as a runnable jar files to the public, however when I was testing today, when I exported it and tried to run it. The files within the packages could not import that Java Commons Library. I know that changing classpath may fix this, but I have  A TON of .java files and don't wish to write them 1 by 1. Also I do not know if the classpath changing technique will allow the compiled jar to work on ANYONE'S computer.

Is there a simpler / faster way to do it? Or is using the Change Classpath with console the only way?

(I am using Eclipse)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It is answered in another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018257/how-to-combine-library-with-my-jar). I've tried to concise the answer for your question below.

> The files within the packages could not import that Java Commons
>   Library.

**Option 1:** You need to ship Java Commons library along with your Jar and mention classpath (relative to your Jar) in your Jar's `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

**Option 2:** You may also place Java Commons library in `lib` folder inside your Jar

You might want to prefer option 2 since you deliver single jar (Fat Jar) instead multiple.

> I have A TON of .java files and don't wish to write them 1 by 1

Just setting classpath would not require you to change your Java files.

> Also I do not know if the classpath changing technique will allow the
>   compiled jar to work on ANYONE'S computer.

I don't know how you want to change classapth. But it certainly works if you choose Option 1 above.

> Is there a simpler / faster way to do it? Or is using the Change
>   Classpath with console the only way?

Eclipse has FatJar plugin to do this.