# How to build a distributable jar with Ant for a java project having external jar dependencies

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I have a Java project in Eclipse with class `MainClass` having main method in package     :

```
com.nik.mypackage.
```

The project also references two external libraries, which I copied in the `lib` folder in Eclipse and then added to build path using `ADD JAR` function. The libraries being `one.jar` and `two.jar`

This library is in `lib` folder in eclipse and added to the build path.

I want to create a executable `JAR` of the application using ant script. So that user can access my application using command:

```
c:>java -jar MyProject-20111126.jar
```

I know about the Eclipse plugin which directly exports a java application as runnable `JAR`. But I want to learn ant and the build process so manually want to create the build.xm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options from your build.xml. You can either unjar the library jars and then bundle their contents with the code compiled for your application. Or, you can put the library jars on the filesystem and supply a ClassPath entry in the manifest file of the MyProject-2011126.jar file.

If you set the classpath in the manifest remember that the path you supply is relative to the MyProject-2011126.jar.

Comment: What if I want to give the distributable to some other user in other machine. In that case how will the option of ClassPath entry in manifest file work ?  And for the first case, unjaring the library jars and budling the contents -- can't ant do that automatically ???

Comment: You can do the unjar/rejar in ant but there isn't a stock task to do it. You'd use the jar tasks. As far as leaving the jars separate it would work fine for other users. The class path is relative to the jar file the the manifest is in. You can use the structure suggested by Surasuin and in the class path in the manifest of my.jar you'd put lib/onijar and lib/two.jar.

Answer (score 1):

one alternative:

Instead of having only a jar, you build mutiple jars (your jar + libs) +batch file.

So, your built package can be like this structure:

```
  -/package/bin/app.bat
   /package/lib/my.jar
   /package/lib/one.jar
   /package/lib/two.jar
```

In app.bat you just have the same as your code

```
java -jar MyProject-20111126.jar
```

PS: if you want to start learning built tools, ANT may be a bit tool old. I suggest http://maven.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please try [one-jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/). It helps to redistribute everything packaged as single jar and comes with [ant-task](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=getting-started&file=ant) .  See [Easiest way to merge a release into one JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/java-easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file).

Comment: Would you be able to include more information about one-jar in your answer?