# How to package libraries into my jar using Ant

Tags: java, ant, jar

My application relies on two external libraries, I have both in `jar` format and have added them to my classpath, making it possible to run my application within NetBeans.

However, I would like to package my application in an easy to use `jar` file. When I tried the  automatic method of `jar` creation provided by NetBeans (where it auto generates a jarfile in `dist/`) and ran it on another computer, I got lots of ClassNotFound (or similar) exceptions for classes that I could tell were supposed to be provided by my other libraries.

Is there a way I can include the other jarfiles I have into my own jar? I've never created an application which relies on other libraries before so this is a first for me.

Comment: I've never distributed using Netbeans IDE, but if helps I used [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) scripts to do so. It feels more comfortable to me when it comes to this kind of library packaging, file moving/copying,etc.

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8277038/95186?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "Class-path" line to your jar's manifest.  The drawback is that you have to hard code the paths to a file system (not jar) location in the manifest.  If you put them all in the same directory or a consistent relative directory, it should be manageable.

See:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Alternately you can try something line One-JAR:  http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/