# Java NoClassDefFoundError caused by external static method

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I'm a long time reader, first time poster.

I use Netbeans to develop a Java application to run some simulations in regard to Project Management. Now the program is finished, I want to make a JAR file of it so other team members can use it without installing Netbeans. Normally I just press "build and clean" to make a JAR file but this trick ain't working this time. When I run the JAR file everything works fine until I press the button to start the simulations. Next error is given on the command line in cmd:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: optimizat
ion/Lmder_fcn
        at umontreal.iro.lecuyer.randvar.BetaGen.nextDouble(BetaGen.java:109)
        at Scheduling.SimulationEngine.randomizeDurations(SimulationEngine.java:
122)
        at Scheduling.SimulationEngine.simulateNew(SimulationEngine.java:73)
        at IO.FileReader_GUI$GUIEventHandler.actionPerformed(FileReader_GUI.java
... blablabla
```

Point given is that the `umontreal.iro.lecuyer.randvar.BetaGen.nextDouble()` method is a static method used from a JAR file I added to my project. In Netbeans it doesn't bring any problems but it does when I use run it 'stand-alone' without Netbeans. 

Can somebody please give me a quick solution? Please keep in mind that I'm not a professional programmer. Do not hesitate to ask questions if you need more information!

Comment: *"Can somebody please give me a quick solution?"*  Hire a consultant at 'urgent' rates.

Comment: How do you run the jar file? If you are using "java -jar myjar.jar" from the command line, remember to include the other jars in your classpath.

Comment: *long time readers* should create an account, get 15 rep points as quick as possible and start upvoting the questions and answers that helped them. IMHO.

Comment: Your problem is that your exported JAR does not contain the required dependencies. You can start reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722257/building-jar-that-includes-all-its-dependencies) for some possible solutions.

Comment: @Perception, I've read the link, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty clear that your JAR is not in the class path. Please read this tutorial, it should help you figure out your problem in your environment.

[PATH and CLASSPATH (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Classes > The Platform Environment)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Also, in the comments @Perception included a [great link that might also help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722257/building-jar-that-includes-all-its-dependencies), I want to make sure you see it.