# making a single-jar java application

Tags: java, jar, executable

If I have a java project that consists of several different types of files (pictures, sound, etc) and multiple jar dependencies, what is a good way to package it all into one single jar that can just be double-clicked?

I know jars by themselves are pretty dumb in that they don't look within themselves for files that they depend on (something I only realized after the slightest bit of frustration (understatement)). -- If jar A depends on classes contained inside jar B, putting jar B inside jar A will not work. Jar A must be in the same directory as jar B.

...Now, I know I could just extract all the files from all the other jars and put everything in the same directory. That *would* sort of work, but I don't want to do it because: 1. It would be messy and 2. it still wouldn't solve the problem of needing to have the sound files in the same directory as the final jar. (For whatever reason, sound files act the exact same way as internal jars)

Basically, I just want to make it so that the files my application depends on aren't obnoxiously visible and ostentatious. So, if there were some solution where I could put everything inside a jar and have it be the only necessary file to run the entire program, that would be optimal. But, I am willing to accept creative/inventive ways to bypass the problem, such as having a batch script in a parent directory execute the jar or something. (I say "or something" because that exact scenario would only work on windows operating systems. ...you know what I mean!)

Comment: how are you accessing your resources (sound files etc)? as files or as getResource()?

Comment: I'm passing their file name into a File object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract all the JARs and merge them into one common JAR.  There are ANT tasks and Maven plugins readily available for doing just this.  Additionally, if you're application is properly written, there is nothing preventing you from putting media files and other resources in the JAR as well.  You just need to ensure that these resources are "[loaded from the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)", rather than being loaded from the current working directory.

Comment: How would I... "load from the classpath", exactly? I'm using 2 methods of playing sound; one is jmf, which accepts sound files as a URL object, and one is Clip, which accepts the sound files as File objects

Comment: Can you include some absolute package / class names?  javax.sound.sampled.Clip provides a open(AudioInputStream stream) method, which can be instantiated using a regular InputStream - such as the one provided by getResourceAsStream().

Comment: Well, wouldn't using an absolute path name be pretty bad..? Because then all you'd have to do is move the jar somewhere else, and all of a sudden it doesn't work any more. ...And sure, Clip can do that, so I guess I'll go try that now, but with jmf, javax.media.Manager can only create Players from DataSources, MediaLocators, and URLs. What about that?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use an absolute path name at all, at least not a file-system path.  You can nest things in folders within the classpath (which I'd recommend doing for organization, and to prevent naming conflicts) - all of which will be contained within your JAR.  I've not done too much with the JMF API, but the .getResource() method will return a URL to a resource on the classpath - even within a JAR, that may be supported.  At worst, you could provide your own PullDataSource implementation that reads from an InputStream.

Comment: I'm getting kind of confused about what you mean by class path.. is this something I specify in the jar manifest, some statement I use in the code, some way I organize my directories, or what?

Comment: The classpath is basically a concept for how Java loads resources.  Specifically, it abstracts how Java classes are loaded - whether directly from the file system, a JAR file, a web server, or another resource.  The same can be used to load any other type of resource as well.  Referring back to your original question, if you can implement your code to support loading everything "from the classpath", you can keep everything within a single Jar - all Java code and media files alike.

Comment: Well then, how WOULD I make my code load everything from the classpath?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5420/discussion-between-ziesemer-and-pojo)

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) plus [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) will do exactly what you need.

Check out the [executable JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) example.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the assembly plugin for maven, you can have it download dependencies, build modules and produce an executable jar.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven, then I suggest the [shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or assembly plugins. 
If not, then read this: [Easiest way to merge a release into one JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/java-easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

If you are building an executable jar and have other jars that you need to be available in the classpath, there is a Class-Path: line in the jar's MANIFEST.MF file that lists entries (including jars and directories) to include in the classpath when the main class is run.

I usually use my IDE or ant to build such executable jars and set the Class-Path: header.

By the way, to make your jar executable, set the Main-Class: line in your MANIFEST.MF file.

Here is an example from an executable jar I build:

```
Main-Class: com.example.app.MyAppCLI
Class-Path: log4j.jar driver.jar libraries.jar
```

And here is a corresponding ant target to build this:

```
<target name="exejar">
  <jar destfile="myapp.jar"
       basedir="bin"
       include="**/app/*.class">
    <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.example.app.MyAppCLI"/>
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="log4j.jar driver.jar libraries.jar"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar>
</target>
```

If you will use a tool like ant to build your executable jars, it will make the process more easy to repeat, and will also handle strange edge cases for you, like what happens when a header line in MANIFEST.MF gets too long.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, you may a appreciate the [onejar-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/). One major benefit is that all your dependency jars stay in jars, and your code is in its own jar. All of those jars are put in a bigger jar, which is made executable, thus avoiding some potential classpath issues. Read the [usage guide](http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavensite/usage.html) and this [blog post](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/03/22/executable-jar-with-onejar-maven-plugin/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

> have a java project that consists of several different types of files (pictures, sound, etc) and multiple jar dependencies, what is a good way to package it all into one single jar that can just be double-clicked

A better way to deploy a rich client app. is using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The end user would never see a Jar, and could be provided a desktop short-cut or menu item to launch the app.