# play .wav file from jar as resource using java

Tags: java, audio, resources, jar

I want to play a .wav file using java code which is in a jar file as resource. My code is look like this -

```
try {
     URL defaultSound = getClass().getResource("/images/ads/WindowsNavigationStart.wav");
     // getClass().getSy.getResource("/images/ads/WindowsNavigationStart.wav");
     File soundFile = new File(defaultSound.toURI());
     AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
     Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
     clip.open(audioInputStream);
     clip.start( );
} catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The file WindowsNavigationStart.wav is exist in one of my jar file. But getting the following exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:363)
at au.com.webscan.wwwizard.app.admin.customfile.UpOneLevelFolder.btnUpFolderActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at au.com.webscan.wwwizard.app.admin.customfile.UpOneLevelFolder.access$000(Unknown Source)
at au.com.webscan.wwwizard.app.admin.customfile.UpOneLevelFolder$1.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Please give me a solution. Thank you all.

Comment: Where is your wav ? If it zipped with your java, you cannot create File object with URI. However, to use the InputStream is possible.

Comment: It is in a jar file created by ant build.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
```

To:

```
System.out.println("defaultSound " + defaultSound);  // check the URL!
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultSound);
```

Comment: I get the following `defaultSound jar:file:/E:/console2012/console2012/lib/pics-webcommerce.jar!/images/ads/WindowsNavigationStart.wav
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL`, Error in my wav file?

Comment: Wav is a 'container format'.  It might have many different types of encodings.  Java only understands some of those encodings.  Try it with the left/right wav available at this [sample media](http://pscode.org/media/#sound) page.

Comment: Hello, this works for me. 
try{ URL defaultSound = this.getClass().getResource(thePathToFile);
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultSound);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audioInputStream);
clip.start();
} catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried:

```
InputStream is= getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/ads/WindowsNavigationStart.wav");
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
```

Essentially I do not think you can create a File out of a URI in the jar file. But you can pass the input stream directly.

Comment: I get the following exception `java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported`

Comment: @Pritorn, To overcome that IOException, wrap the InputStream in a BufferedInputStream. Full solution would be: `InputStream is= getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/ads/WindowsNavigationStart.wav");
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));`

Comment: Thanks for the BufferedInputStream tip. It made all the difference to me.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Once you have a handle to the inputStream, get the audioInputStream and do the rest.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("......");
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
```

Comment: I get the following exception `java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported`

Answer (score 2):

**Perfect Solution.......**

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("sounds/beep.au");

String urls=url.toString(); 
urls=urls.replaceFirst("file:/", "file:///");

AudioClip ac=Applet.newAudioClip(new URL(urls));

ac.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my previous answer at [making a single-jar java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300962/making-a-single-jar-java-application/8300995#8300995) .  The title is misleading, but the poster was trying to do something almost identical to you.  Some of the best details are in the link to the chat log.

Answer (score 0):

```
     try {
        AudioPlayer.player.start(new AudioStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sound/SystemNotification.wav")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked fine for me:

```
public void playSound() {
        InputStream in;
        try {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(
                    getClass().getClassLoader()
                            .getResource("com/kaito/resources/sound.wav").getPath())));
            AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following allows me to play a sound in Eclipse project and an exported jar file:
 - note the BufferedInputStream is used
 - Note, inputStream is used instead of file.

In my main():

```
playAlarmSound();
```

in my class:

```
public static void playAlarmSound() {
ClassLoader classLoader = App.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("alarmsound.wav");
try {
  Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
  AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
  clip.open(ais);
  clip.start();
} catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
  System.err.println("ERROR: Playing sound has failed");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like Kal wrote :

> 1. InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("......");
> 2. AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(is);...

I did just that and it didn't work at first but the problem of "java.io.IOException" was that I used File.separator and for some reason win 8.1 couldn't handle "\\"...

```
public AudioInputStream getSound(String fileName){
    InputStream inputSound;
    AudioInputStream audioInStr;
    String fs = File.separator;

    try {
       absolutePath = fs +packageName+ fs +folderName+ fs +fileName;
       inputSound = getClass().getResourceAsStream(absolutePath);

       //if null pointer exception try unix, for some reason \\ doesn't work on win 8.1
       if(inputSound == null) {
           absolutePath = "/" + packageName + "/" + folderName + "/" + fileName;
           inputSound = getClass().getResourceAsStream(absolutePath);
       }

       audioInStr = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputSound));
       return audioInStr;
    }
```