# NullPointerException when loading file from res folder - Java

Tags: java, audio

So I use this code:

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File audioFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("pop.wav").getFile());

    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

    AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();

    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

    Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    audioClip.open(audioStream);
    audioClip.start();
```

But every time it gives me a NullPointerException.
The file (pop.wav) is inside src/res. But if a put it on my desktop and instead of `classLoader.getResource("pop.wav").getFile()` I put `C:/Users/gebruiker/Desktop/pop.wav` it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425481/play-wav-file-from-jar-as-resource-using-java

Comment: more details on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573679/open-resource-with-relative-path-in-java

Comment: Will you consider accepting the answer? Merry Xmas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources are **not** Files.

Try this:

```
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass ().getResourceAsStream ("/res/pop.wav"));
```

And of cause check path for that pop.wav. sometimes absolute paths within .jar ( /pop.wav ) are easier to manage.

Comment: Where is pop.wav in your jar?

Comment: I don't know if it matters but this method is called on a mousePressed event

Comment: [this is a picture of where pop is in eclipse](http://postimg.org/image/qwbn8o0ll/)

Comment: In that case try /res/pop.wav once

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand it. I am not a really experienced Java programmer.

Comment: See my edit - its important to set right path to resource.

Comment: Yes that works! Thanks a lot, but why did I need to put res before it?

Comment: same as with files: path to directory matters. Relative to your root folder src/ your wave is located in /res/pop.wav. will you accept/upvote the answer please?