# AudioInputStream from InputStream ( load from resource directory)

Tags: java, audio, resources, inputstream, audioinputstream

I try to load my sounds from my resource folder when trying out my Application in the IDE.

For images and other stuff that uses InputStreams I use this method:

```
@Override
public InputStream readAsset(String fileName) throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    return is;
}
```

this lets me open an Inputstream of which I can pull Images.

As soon as I would try to cast this InputStream to an Audio InputStream I get errors. Also if I would try to make a new AudioInputStream passing the above InputStream as the parameter.

This is my current way to load sounds from external paths:

```
public class JavaSound implements Sound {

private Clip clip;


public JavaSound(String fileName){
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {

            //for external storage Path
            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);

            // load the sound into memory (a Clip)
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(sound);
        }
        else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Sound: file not found: " + fileName);
        }
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Malformed URL: " + e);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Unsupported Audio File: " + e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Input/Output Error: " + e);
    }
    catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Line Unavailable Exception Error: " + e);
    }


}

@Override
public void play(float volume) {

    // Get the gain control from clip
    FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

    // set the gain (between 0.0 and 1.0)
    float gain = volume;
    float dB = (float) (Math.log(gain) / Math.log(10.0) * 20.0);
    gainControl.setValue(dB);

    clip.setFramePosition(0);  // Must always rewind!
    clip.start();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    clip.close();
}
}
```

how can i exchange the AudioInputStream part to work like the first code, pulling the files out of my resource directory?

EDIT :
this way of creating a new AudioInputStream by passing an InputStream

```
File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

            //for external storage Path
            AudioInputStream sound = new AudioInputStream(is);

            // load the sound into memory (a Clip)
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(sound);
}
```

also throws errors before even running it

Comment: I do not see a constructor for `AudioInputStream` that only accepts an input stream. [This Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html) indicates the options are `AudioInputStream(InputStream stream, AudioFormat format, long length)` or `AudioInputStream(TargetDataLine line)`. The method `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream stream)` appears to take the input stream alone (as suggested in the answer). However, note the limitations in the Javadocs.

Comment: lol how am i supposed to know the length in frames...how annoying is that?
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream stream) this does not work! It throws a runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this made it work in my above code:

```
public JavaSound(String fileName){
    try {

        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        // load the sound into memory (a Clip)
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(sound);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Malformed URL: " + e);
    }
    catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Unsupported Audio File: " + e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Input/Output Error: " + e);
    }
    catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Sound: Line Unavailable Exception Error: " + e);
    }


}
```

just had to start a new bufferedInputStream with my inputStream to have the AudioInputStream... :D still thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Glad you found the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast `InputStream` to `AudioInputStream` (you could do the inverse). The `Clip.open()` wants an AudioInputStream.

An approach, suggested [by this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425481/play-wav-file-from-jar-as-resource-using-java) is to use the URL from the `.getResource()` call, rather than attempting to open the InputStream and then pass that in.

Therefore, try:

```
URL soundURL = classloader.getResource(fileName);
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL);
```

Comment: I tried both:
see my edit above
but it gave me error too.

Comment: @railwanderer, OK. That's the limit of my working knowledge with the Audio system. I'll delete this answer in a bit since it doesn't help. Sorry neither approach worked.

Comment: no problem still thank you very much for trying to help me :) when i figure it out I ll post the solution

Comment: can i avoid using this clip thing at all and just go with regular streams and some .out method? :D

Comment: @railwanderer, The thing is, having just done a quick search, is that [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425481/play-wav-file-from-jar-as-resource-using-java) seems to imply using the `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream() and sending it the `URL` rather than the `InputStream` should work.

Comment: @railwanderer, updated the answer to suggest using a URL. Hope that works!

Comment: i can´t get it to work properly :( if you want to take a closer look at my poor game framework see here: https://github.com/Railwanderer/AndroidGameFramework

its downloadable and testable. the java module being the javalib folder

it keeps telling me the file would not exist but see yourself its definitely in the right place. the first method for images worked too

Comment: did you take a look at my repository? :)