# Java program without command line

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line

I'm working on a simple chatBot, just as a learning experience, and have hit a block. I have a rudimentery GUI setup that launches when I run the program with the command line, but not when I double-click the Jar. I am either missing code or exporting/running the program incorectly. Im using eclipse and exporting as a runnable jar. If anyone could point me towards a tutorial or some code that would be greatly appreciated.

Clarification...
I want my chatBot to open a GUI when double-clicked, similar to the minecraft-server jar

**EDIT** I figured out what was wrong, it had nothing to do with the manifest or code... I was just executing a while loop wrong, I feel dumb now :(

Comment: What is your main class?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300962/making-a-single-jar-java-application

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your jar 'runnable' in the command line, you need to specify which class is the main class to execute.

This is done by specifying a manifest.txt file that contains the following line:

```
Main-Class: the_package_and_name_of_your_main_class
```

How this manifest file is added to your jar depends on your build tool.

Answer (score 0):

I second to Jason. 
Alternatively you may create one batch file (.bat) unless you want to make it work even on Linux (in this case you would .sh file).

Comment: The jar runs fine from the command line, but it will not open the gui when i double-click the jar