# Easiest way to create JAR?

Tags: java, jar

I am familiar with two ways to create JAR

1)Use Eclipse and export Runnable JAR - quick and easy

2) Use `JarOutputStream` . In addition i have to specify manifest , make sure to include all third parties API that I used in my project . These complicated the code .

The advantage of the second method is that it's done programmatically .

I am curious is there any API that would generate JAR as easy as Eclipse does  ?

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile ("C:\\ ... myProjectFolder")
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`jar` command?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Comment: Even though it may not look that way, doing those stuff on command line is very easy

Comment: You may also find some useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file?rq=1

Comment: What about learning Maven? Definitely will come handy in the future. http://maven.apache.org/

Comment: Using a command line build tool (ant, maven, gradle, and others) will also let you play nicely with dependency management and continuos integration systems.  All big pluses.

Comment: What is difficult with method 1?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might want a build scripting tool. Popular choices include [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). I personally like a newer option called [Buck](http://facebook.github.io/buck/).