# How to convert multiple jars into a single .dex file

Tags: android, dex, dx

I have multiple jar files I would like to compile into a single dex file.

To compile 1 jar into a dex, you can use the following command:

```
dx --dex --output="/tmp/dx.dex" "/tmp/input.jar"
```

Is there a way to compile multiple jars into a single dex file?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of answers on StackOverflow about how to combine multiple jars into a single jar (which you can then dex).  Here's one of them:
[Easiest way to merge a release into one JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file?lq=1)