# Create executable jar including class files, manifest and external jars

Tags: java, jar, external, executable-jar, .class-file

I have two class files: `Generator.class(Main)` and `Approach.class(Helper)`, which are created when I compile Generator.java code. The code is dependent on two external jars - `argparse4j-0.7.0.jar` and `org.apache.commons.io.jar`.

In normal scenario, if I need to execute the code, I would have to run below :

`java -cp .:argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:org.apache.commons.io.jar Generator`

I want to create a jar file so that it is easy to share a single file.

One approach that I found was, to include below in the jar file (Main.jar) -
1. Generator.class
2. Approach.class
3. manifest.txt

Manifest file : manifest.txt

```
Main-Class: Generator
Class-Path: argparse4j-0.7.0.jar org.apache.commons.io.jar
```

In this case, I need to share below 3 with the user -
1. Main.jar
2. org.apache.commons.io.jar
3. argparse4j-0.7.0.jar
To run the jar :- `java -jar Main.jar`

Is it possible to create a single jar file (Main.jar) with below files -
1. Generator.class
2. Approach.class
3. org.apache.commons.io.jar
4. argparse4j-0.7.0.jar
5. manifest.txt

Then only Main.jar needs to be shared with the user and it can be run using : `java -jar Main.jar`

I gave this a try with the same manifest file as mentioned above but the java command fails to run the jar.

Comment: Kindly go through the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81260/easiest-way-to-merge-a-release-into-one-jar-file) for your required solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. It was very informative. But none of the approach worked for me easily.
I looked around and found assemble plugin (maven) which directed me towards using the shade plugin (maven).
This was very easy at worked very well.